# Test React component with async function with mockResolvedValue - the promise is not resolved

Tags: reactjs, promise, jestjs, es6-promise, react-testing-library

I have a component that get an async function and run it.

code sample:

```
const Foo = ({func}) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);
  useEffect(()=> {
        async function myAsyncFunf() {
          const newVar = await func();
          setVal(newVar)
        };
        myAsyncFunf();
      },[]);
  return <div>{val}</div>
}
it('test',async()=>{
  const asyncMock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(43);
  const props = {func: asyncMock}
  const {getByText} = render(<Foo {...props}/>);
  await wait(() => expect(asyncMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
  getByText('43');

});
```

The test is failed with this message:

console.error
Warning: An update to Foo inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

```
When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at
```

Answer (score 0):

in your component, func is actually related to props, you just named it "func"

you need to destructure it in order to access func, or to explicitly access the property of the object.

**Option 1** - Destructuring. Notice the curly braces "{func}"

```
const Foo = ({func}) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);
  useEffect(()=> {
        async function myAsyncFunf() {
          const newVar = await func();
          setVal(newVar)
        };
        myAsyncFunf();
      },[]);
  return <div>{val}</div>
}
```

**Option 2** - Accessing the property "func" of "props"

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);
  useEffect(()=> {
        async function myAsyncFunf() {
          const newVar = await props.func();
          setVal(newVar)
        };
        myAsyncFunf();
      },[]);
  return <div>{val}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a different error message. What should I wrap with act?

Comment: No. I fixed the missing destructure as you suggested. Now I get different error. I updated the question with the new error.